# How to get formula to iterate from a list of numbers?

Tags: python

I defined a formula to calculate the volume of a tube. I want to introduce a list of volumes for a pipette to automatically lower itself with the amount of solution left.

I was able to get it to work with one volume amount, but I would like to be able to pass a list of values, which I keep on getting back an error for.

```
from opentrons import protocol_api
import math
import numpy as np

# metadata
metadata = {
    'protocolName': '2.27.23 - Highthroughput synthesis of Cs3Sb2X9',
    'apiLevel': '2.13'}

def run(protocol: protocol_api.ProtocolContext):
    #labware
    right_tiprack= protocol.load_labware('opentrons_96_tiprack_300ul', '1')
   
    left_tiprack= protocol.load_labware('opentrons_96_tiprack_20ul','5')
    left_tiprack_two= protocol.load_labware('opentrons_96_tiprack_20ul','4')
    
    tuberack= protocol.load_labware('opentrons_15_tuberack_nest_15ml_conical','8')
    
    #plates
    Cs_OPA_plate= protocol.load_labware('corning_96_wellplate_360ul_flat', '6')
    
    
    final_two_plate = protocol.load_labware('corning_96_wellplate_360ul_flat', '3')
    temp_mod = protocol.load_module('temperature module', '9')
    final_one_plate = temp_mod.load_labware('corning_96_wellplate_360ul_flat')
    temp_mod.set_temperature(70)  
    # Volume to transfer from each well
   
    #Depth of tube 117.50 mm
    #diameter of tube 14.90 mm
    Sb = tuberack.wells_by_name()['A1']
    tol = tuberack.wells_by_name()['B1']
    Cs = tuberack.wells_by_name()['C1']
    
    #Change to the amount of solution using in mL
    volume_of_sb_tube_in_ml: float = 2
    volume_of_tol_tube_in_ml:float= 13
    Volume_of_Cs_tube_in_ml: float = 1
    
    #pipette
    
    right_pipette = protocol.load_instrument('p300_single_gen2', 'right', tip_racks=[right_tiprack])
    left_pipette= protocol.load_instrument('p20_multi_gen2','left',tip_racks=[left_tiprack,left_tiprack_two])
    
    # calculation of 15 ml tube intiial heights
    def calc_initial_15(vol):
        dh = -(15.9- vol)*1000/(math.pi*(7.45**2))- 8
        return dh
    
    Sb_intial= calc_initial_15(volume_of_sb_tube_in_ml)
    Toluene_initial= calc_initial_15(volume_of_tol_tube_in_ml)
    Cs_initial= calc_initial_15(Volume_of_Cs_tube_in_ml)
    
    heights = {
        'Sb':Sb_intial,
        'tol': Toluene_initial,
        'Cs': Cs_initial
       
    }
    
    #Def for all, mix step for dilution, dilution, lower pipette for mixing, change for distrubute pick up/drop tip,
    def height_track15_tol(reagent):
        nonlocal heights
       

        dh = [vol/(math.pi*(7.45**2)) for vol in volume_amount]
        dh=np.array(dh)
        if heights[reagent] - dh < -116:
            heights[reagent] = -116
        else:
            heights[reagent] -= dh
  
    for well_name_tol in ['B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1']:
         volume_amount= np.array([150,225,263,282,290,295,297])
        height_track15_tol('tol')
        h = heights['tol']
        right_pipette.pick_up_tip()
        right_pipette.transfer([150,225,263,282,290,295,297], 
                                   tol.top(h), 
                                   [Cs_OPA_plate.wells_by_name()[well_name_tol]], new_tip='never', touch_tip= True)
        right_pipette.drop_tip()
```

I keep on getting back error codes that say that formula can't work with float numbers so I tried to change it to an array then I get this error code :

```
ValueError [line 76]: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

```py
        if heights[reagent] - dh < -116:
            heights[reagent] = -116
        else:
            heights[reagent] -= dh
```

with this, which doesn't use `if`:

```py
        heights[reagent] = np.maximum(-116, heights[reagent] - dh)
```

Comment: `np.maximum` (or `np.clip`) is the one you are looking.  `np.max` is element wise maximum of an array

Comment: @Tarifazo Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize both of those existed!

Comment: Yes np.maximum worked better. Although I still have a bug since I am getting "List of volumes should be equal to number of transfers"